# Как сделать проверку на текст

Tags: python, discord

и так, мне нужна проверка на input, у меня есть переменная botavatar = input('Bot avatar: ')
как мне сделать проверку на то, если переменная botavatar пустая, то в эту переменную записывалось другое значение, а если переменная не пустая, то значение в ней оставалось прежнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте примерное решение вашей проблемы

```
botavatar = input('Bot avatar: ')
if len(botavatar) == 0:
    botavatar = 'test'
```

В случае если пользователь не введёт ничего в переменную botavatar

Вывод будет `test`

Если пользователь ввёл к примеру "user",то в переменной botavatar останется user

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы можете проверять в условии переменную:

Условие: Если к переменной присвоено значение `None`, то срабатывает условие, иначе ничего не происходит.

```
botavatar = input('Bot avatar: ')
if not botavatar: 
    botavatar = 'другая строка'
```

Answer (score -1):

Простая проверка, не равен ли botavatar пустой строке нам подходит.

```
botavatar = input('Bot avatar: ')

if botavatar == '':
    botavatar = 'other value'
```